# proving $ e^{\pi} > \pi ^{e}$

Tags: inequality

I want to show that $ e^{\pi} > \pi ^{e}$?

I was trying to make some functional relations to verify this but I am not able to do so . Any help or hints will be helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: I think this was asked here before.

Comment: Take logarithms on both the side and see what you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a = e^{\pi}$ and $b = \pi ^{e}$.

Taking logarithms we obtain $a > b$ iff  $\frac  {\log e}{e} > \frac  {\log \pi}{\pi}$

Now consider the function $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$ and check when $f$ is decreasing?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the function $$f(x)=\frac{\log x}x$$

You're looking at $x^y<y^x$, or equivalently $f(x)<f(y)$.